# After Facebook Login redirect to Device user form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a user registration form. In which I have facebook login button. I want fetch information from facebook and display that information in user registration form. How can I do this?
I use `omniauth_facebook` and I successfully login with that but I don't want login. I want to display that facebook information on my user registration form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JasonTruluck & @stsd Thanks for your support.

I done this and I'm Using [OmniAuth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

In my controller I define this

```
private

  def authentication_sign_in
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    session[:omniauth] = {:firstname => user.firstname, :lastname => user.lastname, :email => user.email }
    session[:provider] = omniauth['provider']
    session[:uid] = omniauth['uid']
    redirect_to new_member_registration_url
  end
```

**And In my Registration Controller**

```
def new
  if session[:omniauth]
    resource = build_resource(session[:omniauth])
  else
    resource = build_resource({})
  end
  respond_with resource
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a rails cast help you manage OpenID, twitter and facebook authentication services in your project:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gem like [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) or [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) to get the users information since you have their access token and then fill the form with their information as such:

Using fb_graph:

```
user = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN).fetch
```

Then in your form:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="first_name" value="<%= user.first_name %>">
   <input type="text" id="last_name" value="<%= user.last_name %>">
   ....
</form>
```

This will fill the form with the users information, but why not just create the user in your callback function when logging in with Facebook since you will have to login to get the token anyways?